# Returning number of participants as async in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

I would like return number of participants as a JSON format. I have a `ParticipantRepository` class that is below:

```
public async Task<int> GetCountAllParticipants()
{
    return await context.Participants
    .CountAsync();
}
```

And my `ParticipantsController` class is below:

```
[HttpGet("all/count")]
public JsonResult GetCountAllParticipants()
{
    return Json(repo.GetCountAllParticipants());
}
```

This has no errors on the code but it returns self referencing loop as below:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected for property 'task' with type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[System.Int32,Restore.API.Repositories.ParticipantRepository.ParticipantRepository+d__15]'. Path 'stateMachine.<>t__builder'.

When I modify repository as below:

```
public async Task<int> GetCountAllParticipants()
{
    return context.Participants.Count();
}
```

This time, I get this error:

> This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread

But I have the correct returned JSON abject as below:

```
{
    "result": 8,
    "id": 1,
    "exception": null,
    "status": 5,
    "isCanceled": false,
    "isCompleted": true,
    "isCompletedSuccessfully": true,
    "creationOptions": 0,
    "asyncState": null,
    "isFaulted": false
}
```

I can use it like that but I don't think this is the right way to do it. How can I return the number of participants? What would be the "right" way to do that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have to await the entire chain.  Thus you would do:

```
public async Task<int> GetCountAllParticipants()
{
    return await context.Participants.CountAsync();
}

[HttpGet("all/count")]
public async Task<JsonResult> GetCountAllParticipants()
{
    return Json(await repo.GetCountAllParticipants());
}
```

If this is .NET Framework (and not Core) then you might want .ConfigureAwait(false) at the end of the async method calls so it doesn't get forced to resume on the UI thread... But only if you don't care about the language/culture settings.

Edit: If you want to return a specific json property like you mentioned then you would do:

```
[HttpGet("all/count")]
public async Task<JsonResult> GetCountAllParticipants()
{
    var count = await repo.GetCountAllParticipants()
    return Json(new { result = count });
}
```

However, this would treat it as a #, if you want it to be a "" (string) then do:

```
[HttpGet("all/count")]
public async Task<JsonResult> GetCountAllParticipants()
{
    var count = await repo.GetCountAllParticipants()
    return Json(new { result = count.ToString() });
}
```

Comment: This returns 8 which is the correct number. But It's JSON object without proper JSON format. No parenthesis or anything. I can still use it. But I was expecting something like `{ result: "8" }`.

Comment: Edit for that above

Answer (score -1):

I think it is duplicate of 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34501661/3623172

You use ToListAsync() and then return the count()

Comment: It may be the similar title but the codes and approaches are fairly different. Also, I disagree that we can use `ToListAsnc()` first then `Count()`. This returns an error.

Comment: This is not a good approach. CountAsync() will perform a SELECT COUNT(*). ToListAsync() and .Count() will first bring all of the data to the client and then perform a count.